# Facebook Share Dialog: Disable the "Group/Publicity" Select Box

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, feed

is it possible to disable this little box:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IHMAOZz.png]

Or maybe one can set this box with no publicity selection. The background of this is that users get incentives based on their sharing. But this would be a loss for me, when somebody shares with none exposure to their friends.

Thank you very much!

Comment: _“The background of this is that users get incentives based on their sharing.”_ – that is a violation of [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). And the question to _rob_ the user of their privacy controls is ridiculous in itself – of course that is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didnt know this is a violation